# How to uncheck style rule for single element in chrome DevTools?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

I have a CSS rule like this:

`.blah-blah div`

That rule hits many `div`s on the page. When I uncheck that rule for any element in Chrome DevTools I think it "disables" the rule for all elements that it applies to. Is there any way to only uncheck that rule for the current element in question?

Comment: No, there is not. You can manually add an id to this element in HTML and edit the generic selector to have `:not(#that_id)`

Comment: Or add a style to the element directly

Answer (score 1):

DevTools technical writer here. You're right. When you uncheck a general rule like this:

```
p {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

It'll disable the rule for all `p` nodes.

One workaround is to select the element in the DOM Tree and then declare a new rule in the `element.style` block that cancels out whatever styling you're trying to suppress.

[image: element.style]

The `element.style` block is equivalent to adding inline styles to the element's HTML via the `style` attribute. The code in the screenshot above maps to this:

```
<p style="margin-top: 48px; background-color: beige;">...</p>
```